# Is it possible to calculate the input variable of a specific encryption function without brute-forcing it?

Tags: functions, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, reverse-math

I didn't know where to post this question, here or SO but I feel it's more of a math problem.

Lately I have been reverse engineering a game, and figured out how it takes user input, encodes it, and verifies it against a specific value to see if the user input is a correct cheat code or not. The game has a unique id for every player and a specific key that it uses for this function. The algorithm looks like this:

```
userInput = ReadUserInput();
userInputEncrypted = userInput MOD encryptionKey;
for i = 0; i<16; i++{
    userInputEncrypted = userInputEncrypted^2 MOD encryptionKey;
}
userInputEncrypted = userInputEncrypted * userInput;
userInputEncrypted = userInputEncrypted MOD encryptionKey;

if (userInputEncrypted == correctValue)
    //Bingo!
```

Now my problem is this:
I know what the correct values are, and I know the encryptionKey, is there a way mathematically to do this in reverse and instantly calculate what the starting userInput should be?

Or am I doomed to bruteforce it as the modulo that occurs 16 times gives me no other choice?

As you can see in the last step, the algorithm re-uses the starting userInput, so my hopes lie there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is 41 bits long.

Comment: I made a mistake, it's actually 65 bits (I confused it with 0x41 which is hex). Still feasible? The number is 19474436171537127533. I can get the factors of that number easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be the encryption key, and $x$ be the userInput, modulo $m$. Then, as mentioned by mihaild, the encryption algorithm is essentially

$$x ^ {2^{16} + 1} \equiv a \pmod m$$

Let $E = 2^{16} + 1 = 65537$. To reverse the encryption, we need to find $D$ such that
$$x^{ED}\equiv x \pmod m$$
for all $x, 0 \le x < m$ and thus
$$a^D\equiv x \pmod m$$

The way to do that, is to solve
$$ED \equiv 1 \pmod \phi(m)$$
where $\phi()$ is [Euler's Totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

For the given
$$m = 19474436171537127533$$
$$\phi(m) = 19474436152198143420$$

Once we know $\phi(m)$, we can find $D$ by using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), since
$$ED - k\phi(m) = 1$$
for some $k$, provided that E is coprime to $\phi(m)$. That's certainly true in this case. In fact, $E$ is prime, and
$$phi(m) \equiv 35631 \pmod E$$

Below is a short Sage Python script that performs the necessary calculations. For convenience, I used Sage to find $\phi(m)$, but its easy to calculate it from the prime factors of $m$:
$p = 1065734711$, and
$q = 18273249403$,
since
$$\phi(pq) = (p-1)(q-1)$$
when $p$ and $q$ are prime.

Sage isn't necessary for the subsequent calculations, since plain Python has arbitrary precision integer arithmetic, and an efficient power modulus function.

#### Code

```
m = 19474436171537127533
#print(factor(m))
#m = 1065734711 * 18273249403
#print(euler_phi(m))
phi = 19474436152198143420
E = 65537 # 2^16 + 1
#print(xgcd(E, phi))
# g, s, t : g = s * E + t * phi
# (1, -6901944375041675347, 23227)
#D = -6901944375041675347
#print(D+phi)
D = 12572491777156468073
# D*E % phi == 1
#print(D*E % phi)

@interact
def test(n=12345):
    # Encrypt
    a = pow(n, E, m)
    print(a)
    # Decrypt
    x = pow(a, D, m)
    print(x)
```

#### Output

```
10240177983085547351 
12345
```

And here's a [live version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtkN1qwzAMhe_9FIIwiFsPIlu2mkJhF8lrbITW_WFLGlKPtW8_JW3XMeYbYenTOT5uYQVYEhO5gIzeMVr2zqmsHw5dyrfNOh2HvNVaZe3IFsGzI0aEGeDCsrNUUvHDx8-POLz1-8O0IvW3vrdYLpAc2ULVMghe_CAD-4oB5oB3kfNuvclrA7I--sLOwMlAgiXsZOskzrXgSaoQMs_RwHMoCzEix74gDJKB2IB11rJIVLL3H3F3rOajlxoxtJ4lEzLLdwQKi4IlHVSzGp5gCrR6vFS67_FyHWilXqQXB_kytYlbSPGU8m6F1pHXSwVyMqi79XDp03RrxK4_fuWdAUnb6ql5FW70ja_igz_f-MZA9Yc_62-dIG6N&lang=sage) of the script that you can play with, running on the SageMathCell server. (The script isn't stored on the server, it's encoded into the URL).

FWIW, this is essentially the process of cracking [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)), except that proper RSA uses a *much* larger modulus; these days it's recommended that $m$ be at least 1024 bits so $p$ & $q$ can't feasily be found.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort I appreciate it.
I tried your script, and changed E to 2^15 + 1 since there is actually one less iteration happening before multiplying to the starting userdata. I then did the extended euclidean algorithm to what I had and the result was
(3, -20800307160027313, 35) 
which I think is not proper for what I want? What should I do next?
Thanks again

Comment: @PanosPaschalis Oh. In that case, we have a small problem. The factors of phi are `2^2 * 3 * 5 * 106573471 * 3045541567` and the above method *needs* E to be coprime to phi, otherwise ED=1 mod phi has no solution, but 32769 = `3^2 * 11 * 331`. There *may* be a way around that, but I'll have to think about it, and it's after 2 AM in my timezone.

Comment: @Panos A major issue is that when E shares a factor with phi, then $x^E=a \pmod m$ isn't a one-to-one function, so there are multiple inverses for a given $a$. Here's a script that illustrates that for a very small example, $m=35$: [script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjcEKwjAMhu99ioCXBHrSeREGvod4aLXTMteWNsPh05t2g-WQ5A9f_n-CHk5ndYD09rIeO2VkZBNeDidSpariGA0pdfWBXTYPVk83ALvCuPQdXRRIWQFvKX5x1rBomAiGmGEGH8DcG1Hs5mWp6ThWLUfppl1SlgSMo4aPC1gsraAfIEQWfk3aybI51appXNN-PqHRYGmn9w-mPzVtPqs=&lang=sage)

Comment: I'm sorry for putting you into more trouble, my head is tired and I got confused, the iterations are indeed 2^16 + 1 and your script is correct! Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

It's essentially solving
$$x ^ {2^{16} + 1} \equiv a \pmod n$$
($x$ is the input, $a$ is the correct value, $n$ is the encryption key). It is called the  discrete root problem, and it can be found [quite efficiently](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/discrete-root.html) if the factorization of $\phi (n)$ is known, if not - this problem is probably hard.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I need help understanding what you mean however, as I am not too familiar with those terms yet. I have a library that can give me all the divisors of the encryptionKey (I suppose that's the "n" you mention?). What should be my next step with those numbers?

Comment: $n$ is indeed encryption key. You need to apply algorithm from the above link - find primitive root, rewrite the problem as discrete algorithm problem and solve it. There is complete implementation (not the best, but should be enough for $41$ bits).

Comment: I made a mistake, it's actually 65 bits (I confused it with 0x41 which is hex). Still feasible? The number is 19474436171537127533. I can get the factors of that number easily.